# Very simple state change of specific array item in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I'm trying to change the state of only one specific array item from the `reviews` array. How can this be done? This code doesn't seem to work:

```
this.setState({
  reviews[2].current: true
});
```

Here's the full code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

const reviewsInit = [
  {
    name: "Peter Lahm",
    current: null
  },
  {
    name: "Simon Arnold",
    current: null
  },
  {
    name: "Claire Pullen",
    current: null
  }
];

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      name: "React",
      reviews: reviewsInit
    };
  }

  change = () => {
    this.setState({
      reviews[2].current: true
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {console.log(this.state.reviews[2].current)}
        <button onClick={this.change}>click me</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-tbryf5

As you can probably tell I'm new to react! Thanks for any help here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some context, `React` detects state change when reference of the state object changes. It does not track deep changes happening in array or the object.

**Solution**

We need to make another variable with same data (mostly destructuring). Change the value needed. And assign that to state again.

**For Object**

```
this.setState({...oldState, keyToChange: 'newValue'});
```

**For Array**

```
const temp = [...oldState];
temp[index] = 'newValue';
this.setState(temp);
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

It's common for an Array state to copy first then update one of its value

```
  change = () => {
    const result = [...this.state.reviews];
    result[2].current = true;
    this.setState({reviews: result});
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

const reviewsInit = [
{
    name: "Peter Lahm",
    current: null,
},
{
    name: "Simon Arnold",
    current: null,
},
{
    name: "Claire Pullen",
    current: null,
},
];

class App extends Component {
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
        name: "React",
        reviews: reviewsInit,
    };
}

change = () => {
    const prevState = [...this.state.reviews];
    prevState[2].current = true;
    this.setState({
        reviews: prevState,
    });
};

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            {console.log(this.state.reviews[2].current)}
            <button onClick={this.change}>click me</button>
        </div>
    );
}
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```